# Limit range of movement of picker

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

(My issue is with `WKInterfacePicker`, but ideas for standard `UIPickerView` might also be applicable.)

I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how I can limit the range of selectable values on a `WKInterfacePicker`?

To explain: Let's say I have two pickers, A and B. Each has a unique array of values. If the user moves picker A up or down, I make picker B move the opposite direction, by the same index change. The issue is if that movement of picker A is going to exceed the array of B's values (`<0` or `>array.count`). I need to keep the range of selectable values on picker A within the limits of picker B, even though A may have index values higher or lower in its own array.

I have tried creating a 'slice' of picker A's values to match the range of picker B's limits, however this then alters the index numbering on picker A (i.e. index *x* no longer pertains to the same value).

I am ideally looking for a way to stop the user taking picker A past a given index range. Any ideas/thoughts greatly welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No answers received, but thought I would post how I worked this out in case anyone else has this issue.

First, some bugs seem to exist with the `wkinterfacepicker` in its current form, mainly around it not 'settling' correctly on a value under certain circumstances (bug raised with Apple). This means I had to work around this, using a number of the other methods available. Here is the approach I used:

1. (Assumes initial/previously selected values for both `PickerA` and
   `PickerB` have been stored in variables.)
2. Use the `pickerDidFocus`method to trigger a calculation of the
   current position of `PickerB`(from value stored above), and its
   upper/lower limits. Calculate acceptable upper/lower values for `PickerA` based on this range.
3. When `PickerA` is changed, use the default `@IBAction` from the picker
   change to store the selected value in another variable.
4. Use `pickerDidSettle`to wait for the `PickerA` movement to stop before
   doing anything. Calculate change between old and new value of
   `PickerA`, compare against limits calculated earlier. If within range,
   make change to `PickerB`.
5. If outside of range for `PickerB`, pop alert message, and set a flag.
   In `willActivate` for original `InterfaceController`, check for flag
   and, if active, `setSelectedItemIndex` back to within acceptable
   range.

This may seem a little overly complicated. The last step in particular may seem over the top, however sporadic/unreliable behaviour of the pickers I experienced, even when using `pickerDidSettle`, meant that I had to use this approach to guarantee that there was a pause before resetting the pickers.

Maybe this will help someone else!